# How to extract all the values from a specific field of a n*1 structure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, structure, matlab-struct

Assume I have a structure called I of the size n*1, with a multiple fields one of which is called 'area' for example. When I try the code below:

```
area = I.area
```

the resultant area only have the one value that comes from the last position of the structure. Is there any fast way to exact all the values in the field, except using for loop as follows:

```
for ii = 1:n; area(ii) = I(ii).area; end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple `[]` around the struct will result in horizontal concatenation of all values. If you instead want to concatenate them along another dimension, you can use `cat` to specify this explicitly. This will allow you to better handle fields which may contain multiple values.

```
% Concatenate them along the first dimension
out = cat(1, I.area);

% Concatenate them along the third dimension
out = cat(2, I.area);
```

Alternately, if the fields are all *different* dimensions, then turn them into a `cell`

```
out = {I.area};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

```
area = [I.area]
```

`I.area` returns all values of `I(1).area`, `I(2).area` ... as a comma-separated list, which can be plugged into wherever such list is expected, e.g. function parameter list or array initialization.

EDIT: If all `I(i).area` is a row vector with equal size. Then you can first concatenate all of them horizontally, then reshape to desired dimension:

```
area =  reshape([I.area], [2 length(I)])'
```

Result:

```
>> I.area

ans =

     3     4


ans =

     5     6


ans =

     7     8

>> reshape([I.area], [2 length(I)])'

ans =

     3     4
     5     6
     7     8
```

Comment: It works if the area field has one value in each position, such as I(1).area = 1. What if the entry has two value I(1).area = [1, 2]?  Is it possible to extract these values just as they are structured as a matrix rather than shaped into a column or a row. For example:

Comment: If I(1).area = [1, 2], I(2).area = [3, 4], I want the output is [1, 2; 3, 4].

Comment: If your intention is to address cases where `area` is a 2x1 vector, please say so explicitly in your question next time so that answerers do not have to guess what you really mean. And this line `area(ii) = I(ii).area;` strongly suggests `I.area` is a scalar, Anyway, a vector `area` can be easily handled with `reshape`. I've edited my answer to reflect that.